# Python: Extract and save string between special characters using a foor loop

Tags: python, string, substring

I have a longer string which contains numbers seperated by # (see example below). I would like to use a for loop to store the number sequences between characters in individual arrays.

```
#
1 2 3 4 3 8
#
6 9 2 5 7 8
#
2 0 1 6 7 2
#
```

How could I proceed?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? 
And is this a multi line string?

Comment: I tried re.search using '#(.*)#'. The error is: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about plain old loop?

```
for line in long_string.split("\n"):
    if line != '#':
        numbers = list(map(int, line.split(" ")))
        print(numbers)
```

Which outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 8]
[6, 9, 2, 5, 7, 8]
[2, 0, 1, 6, 7, 2]
```

You could also go with

```
for line in long_string.split("\n"):
    try:
        numbers = list(map(int, line.split(" ")))
        print(numbers)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

But be careful as this will completely ignore the lines where there are alphanumeric characters.

Comment: My string contains non-numeric values. The error is: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. Do I have to convert to float?

Comment: I'm guessing it would be the first or last line which would be an empty line. Converting `int('')`  will raise this issue. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `re.findall` here along with a list comprehension:

```py
inp = """#
1 2 3 4 3 8
#
6 9 2 5 7 8
#
2 0 1 6 7 2
#"""

seq = [[int(x) for x in y.split()] for y in re.findall(r'\d+(?:\s+\d+)*', inp)]
print(seq)

# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 8], [6, 9, 2, 5, 7, 8], [2, 0, 1, 6, 7, 2]]
```